# Django 1.8 check if template exists in view

Tags: python, django

Is there a better way to check if a template exists in django 1.8?

Currently, I am doing this in views.py:

```
def get_template_names(self):
    try:
        get_template(self.get_template_name())
        return self.get_template_name()
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return self.get_fallback()
```

I do not feel entirely comfortable to load the template in order to check if I can load the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `get_template_names()` is meant to return a list of templates. So if calculating `get_fallback()` is not expensive, you can call it and include it in the list. Django will use the first template in the list that exists to render the template.

```
def get_template_names(self):
    return ['default_template_name.html', self.get_fallback()]
```